# Spark not able to read hive table because of _1 and _2 sub folders in S3

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I have below 3 hive tables with same structure.

```
drop table default.test1;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `default.test1`(                                                                                                    
`c1` string,                                                                                                                                                                     
`c2` string,                                                                                                                                                                    
`c3` string)                                                                                                                                                                
ROW FORMAT SERDE                                                                                                                                                                        
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'                                                                                                                         
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                                                                                                                                                   
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'                                                                                                                       
OUTPUTFORMAT                                                                                                                                                                            
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'                                                                                                                      
LOCATION                                                                                                                                                                                
's3://s3_bucket/dev/dev/testspark/test1/';

drop table default.test2;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `default.test2`(                                                                                                    
`c1` string,                                                                                                                                                                     
`c2` string,                                                                                                                                                                    
`c3` string)                                                                                                                                                                
ROW FORMAT SERDE                                                                                                                                                                        
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'                                                                                                                         
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                                                                                                                                                   
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'                                                                                                                       
OUTPUTFORMAT                                                                                                                                                                            
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'                                                                                                                      
LOCATION                                                                                                                                                                                
's3://s3_bucket/dev/dev/testspark/test2/';


drop table default.test3;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `default.test3`(                                                                                                    
`c1` string,                                                                                                                                                                     
`c2` string,                                                                                                                                                                    
`c3` string)                                                                                                                                                                
ROW FORMAT SERDE                                                                                                                                                                        
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'                                                                                                                         
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                                                                                                                                                   
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'                                                                                                                       
OUTPUTFORMAT                                                                                                                                                                            
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'                                                                                                                      
LOCATION                                                                                                                                                                                
's3://s3_bucket/dev/dev/testspark/test3/';
```

```
hive>insert into default.test1 values("a","b","c");
hive>insert into default.test2 values("d","e","f");
hive>insert overwrite table default.test3 select * from default.test1 UNION ALL select * from default.test2;
```

Once after I loaded data by using UNION ALL of test1 and test2. test3 table s3 path is having the data in sub folders like below.

```
PRE 1/                                                                                                                                                             
PRE 2/
```

When I query the test3 table from hive it will give the result of the data which was inserted.
But when I query the same in spark. It is getting zero count.
pyspark shell:

```
>>>sqlContext.sql("select * from default.test3").count()
>>>0
```

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Spark version is  2.0

Comment: Just got a thought, If I can make hive to write the output to one single file rather that 2 sub directories, I should be able to read the output table through Spark.

Comment: set hive.exec.reducers.max=1;  I set this property in hive. and executed the insert overwrite stmt. I still see sub folders created. So the issue is not resolved yet.

Answer (score 3):

There is one more property need to be set along with the ones above to make this work.

```
spark.conf.set("mapred.input.dir.recursive","true") 
spark.conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "false")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the below properties before running sqlContext.sql

sqlContext.setConf("mapred.input.dir.recursive","true");
sqlContext.setConf("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true");

Comment: our experiment shows `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "false") ` is also necessary.